# Replace n with n+1

Tags: search, replace

I want to replace a number `n`, with the number `n+1`. Here's what's working:

```
:%s/\([0-9]\+\)/\=(submatch(0)+1)/
```

But this one doesn't work:

```
:%s/-c \([0-9]\+\)/-c \=(submatch(0)+1)/
```

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use `\=` in substitute it needs to start the replacement string (see `:h sub-replace-expression`). Also `substitue(0)` means whole matched string, so also including `-c` prefix and that will always produce 0 when used in a arithmetic context. To use it correctly only on a number, you should use `submatch(1)`.

And now, to make it work, you need to include `-c` inside the expression:

```
s/-c \([0-9]\+\)/\=("-c ".(submatch(1)+1))/
```

or:

```
s/\(-c \)\([0-9]\+\)/\=((submatch(1)).(submatch(2)+1))/
```